# How to generate an array of true/false values by comparing a range (or array) to a single value for use in a filter

Tags: excel, vba

In a worksheet I can do something like:

```
=A1:A10="test"
```

and the results will be an array of 10 true/false values representing if the values of cells A1:A10 are equal to "test".

This method can be used in a filter function in the worksheet (Office 365) something like:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10,A1:A10="test")
```

but anytime I try to make use of this in VBA I can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to generate the true/false results array for use in the filter?

The best I can currently do is looping through every value in the array to check each individually and generate the true/false array that way but if I'm doing that I might as well populate the results array directly, without using the filter function.

Comment: Well, you can always do `arr = [A1:A10="test"]`, a.k.a. `arr = Application.Evaluate("A1:A10=""test""")`.

Comment: Can you share an example of when it didn't work? Add a screenshot, some sample data, and a short description of what is happening and we'll take it from there.

Comment: @gserg I can get this to work now using explicit cell address ("a1:a10") but would really like to be able to feed it a range variable or listcolumn object if not an array, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTER()` can work in VBA.
Eg:

```vb
Dim arr
    
arr = Sheet1.Evaluate("=FILTER(A1:B10,B1:B10=""test"")")
    
Sheet1.Range("D:E").ClearContents
If Not IsError(arr) Then
    Sheet1.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End If
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this solution but feed the formula a range, listcolumn, or array object?  I can see the array being a no-go for this method but the range or listcolumn seem like they should work.

Comment: For the range you’d use the ranges Address and concatenation it into the formula being passed to Evaluate

Comment: That did it, I'm not sure what I did wrong in the past but I thought I had tried concatenate, must have gotten my formatting wrong.
Thanks for everyone's help!