# application.evaluate length limit and possible workarounds

Tags: excel, vba

I had previously asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363415/how-to-generate-an-array-of-true-false-values-by-comparing-a-range-or-array-to/75364247?noredirect=1#comment133002396_75364247)

and now I'm trying to use the solution above in a more flexible way.

Previously, I had set up multiple functions for if I needed my filter array to filter based on 1, 2, or 3 different column values.  I quickly ran into the character limit of the Evaluate function.

```
filterArr = Evaluate(Worksheetfunction.Concat("=let(x, Iferror((", col1.address(,,,true), "=", filterVal1, ")*(", col2.address(,,,true), "=", filterVal2, "),false), if(x=1, true, if(x=true, true, false)))"))
```

I then tried to create a function that would consider a previously created filterArr in place of needing to string together multiple filter criteria:

```
Private Sub test2()

Dim filterArr() As Variant
Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim filterVal1 As Variant
Dim filterVal2 As Variant

Dim test As Variant

Set col1 = Sheets("listSheet").ListObjects("listTable").ListColumns("listCol").DataBodyRange
Set col2 = Sheets("listSheet").ListObjects("listTable").ListColumns("listCol2").DataBodyRange

filterVal1 = "test"
filterVal2 = "test2"

filterArr = Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.Concat("=let(x,iferror((", col1.Address(, , , True), "=""", filterVal1, """),false),if(x=1,true,if(x=true,true,false)))"))
filterArr = Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.Concat("=let(x,iferror((", col2.Address(, , , True), "=""", filterVal2, """)*(", filterArr, "),false),if(x=1,true,if(x=true,true,false)))"))
End Sub
```

The problem here is that the concat function translates my previousResultsArr into a full list of values.  This works on a short list but the worksheets I need it to work on are over 50,000 rows and will get larger.

Comment: Would help to provide an example of what it is you're actually trying to do.  If you want to filter an array by multiple values then most likely a loop over the array is going to be the most flexible approach.

Comment: I'm working on part inspections.  So the biggest table I'm trying to filter has around 30 columns and as I said, around 50,000 rows.  I want to pull just the rows that correspond with whatever grouping I'm looking at and load them into a userform listbox.

So I might want to filter on the Batch, In Use, and Drawing Revision columns.

I'm using the Application.Evaluate function to try and create an array of true/false values that can be fed into the "Include" parameter of worksheetfunction.Filter along with the complete table databodyrange.

Comment: You might consider using Advanced Filter maybe, and copying the filtered rows to another sheet.  You could then set the listbox rowsource to the filtered content.

Comment: I'm not sure the advanced filter will get me where I need to go but it is a helpful new tool I can think about in the future.

I've been able to make the old method work for now, as long as I don't need to add a fourth filter criteria.

Should I mark this solved even if it isn't exactly what I was looking for?